# The request was missing an Authentication Key (FCM Token). Please, refer to section &quot;Authentication&quot; of the FCM documentation

Tags: angular, nativescript

i am sending firebase notifications from my nativescript app using angular httppost module it sometimes sends notifications sometimes it returns error that The request was missing an Authentication Key (FCM Token). Please, refer to section "Authentication" of the FCM documentation

using postman if application is in foreground it does not recieve notification but the response is still success but if app is in background or i press home button on android it recieves notification
here is glimpse of postman

```
sendtoken(id, detail) {
        console.log("????????????????????????????????????????????????");
        console.log(JSON.stringify(detail.firebase_token));
        console.log(JSON.stringify(this.DataService.activeJob));
        console.log("\n\n" + detail.JobID);
        var job = this.DataService.activeJob.filter(f => detail.JobID === f.jobID)[0];

        // + detail.amount + "\n Origin : " + job.jobOrigin + "\nDestination : " + job.jobDestination

        var data = {

            notification: {
                "title": "JOB",
                "text": "Your Firm was allocated a job of amount :",
                "sound": "default"
            },
            "priority": "High",
            "to": detail.firebase_token
        };

        // alert(JSON.stringify(data));
        var ServerSettings =
            {

                serverpath: "https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send"
            };

        this.headers.append("Authorization", "key=AAAA9wyBPKg:APA91bGI6dOOM42iTJNqO47xMC9QIkLHf738Sn1iVk0gbkZDND1fuP9zBW1A38DlhupDdvlsAZCJu1iNACjbVvtdZQd3ePXnq1xctwYQ3PCErchmyYMM4UvmWjeeNjn2X1IL9mgy5ioT");
        this.headers.append("Content-Type", "application/json");
        this.options.headers = this.headers;
        //this.setHeaders();
        console.log("\n\nSending to Server for Update :\n\n" + data);
        let url = ServerSettings.serverpath;

        return this.httpmodule.post(url,data, this.options);

    }
```

with postman

```
 {
        "notification": {
                "title": "JOB",
                "text": "Your Firm was allocated 5",
                "sound": "default"
            },
            "priority": "High",
            "to": "dwu1TEW5sPM:APA91bEppyye2NCq5IAfnjJg95eTsnsPf4Vn3U8CLgvUjJnY7uAVs4ASZiu1RCuFKf7uzXYojAGzKQD8cflKRGvpiqhEymbhK-DB-LQi8MogWIyyIR_xOm64GIpbviWrDuVZt8Td6xZ2"

        }
```

response with postman

```
{
    "multicast_id": 6341518491186981658,
    "success": 1,
    "failure": 0,
    "canonical_ids": 0,
    "results": [
        {
            "message_id": "0:1569773536386430%0a6c29b00a6c29b0"
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> If you always want to display notifications while the application is
>   in foreground withouth sending additional parameters/data when sending
>   the push notification, you need to set the
>   showNotificationsWhenInForeground option to true:

```
firebase.init({
  showNotificationsWhenInForeground: true,
});
```

[Reference from plugin docs](https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/nativescript-plugin-firebase/blob/master/docs/MESSAGING.md#always-show-notifications-when-the-application-is-in-foreground).

**Edit:**

With Angular while updating headers you should replace the existing instance with new one returned by `append` method.

```
this.headers = this.headers.append("Authorization", "key=AAAA9wyBPKg:APA91bGI6dOOM42iTJNqO47xMC9QIkLHf738Sn1iVk0gbkZDND1fuP9zBW1A38DlhupDdvlsAZCJu1iNACjbVvtdZQd3ePXnq1xctwYQ3PCErchmyYMM4UvmWjeeNjn2X1IL9mgy5ioT").append("Content-Type", "application/json");
this.options.headers = this.headers;
```

Comment: not a solution problem is when i send notification from app using angular http post it returns this  "<HTML>\n<HEAD>\n<TITLE>The request was missing an Authentication Key (FCM Token). Please, refer to section &quot;Authentication&quot; of the FCM documentation, at
 https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/server.

Comment: Sorry it was confusing, You had also mentioned **using postman if application is in foreground it does not recieve notification but the response is still success but if app is in background or i press home button on android it recieves notification here** which sounded like you wanted the notification to work when in foreground. Are you using the same auth token in both postman and http client on app?

Comment: yes that was another issue but more important is it  should work  thanks